# Duplicate Session Error hitting AWS instance

Tags: apache-flex, amazon-web-services, blazeds

We have a [Flex application](http://www.dekho.com.au/help/32/ImagesExt/image17_7.jpg) that has a Java backend and we utilise BlazeDS in the middle.
We use Tomcat as the Java Application server, and it works fine for our client-base who self-host the app on either physical or virtual servers.

We have setup a deployment on a new instance on AWS.
We can hit the application fine from the instance itself, but hitting it via it's Public DNS on a browser on my home & work machine I get this message:

> Detected duplicate HTTP-based FlexSessions, generally due to the
>   remote host disabling session cookies. Session cookies must be enabled
>   to manage the client connection correctly.

Our client side logging has a little more info, and you can see that it makes 2 calls before getting the error:

```
6:58:01:542 pm  [INFO] au.com.esriau.dekho.business.AbstractDelegate  - calling SessionService.getSessionInfo
6:58:01:543 pm  [DEBUG] au.com.esriau.dekho.business.AbstractDelegate  - args: (Array)#0
  [0] "0A86A336:0137C62A4BBD:ADB6:1191EBC5"
6:58:01:544 pm  [INFO] au.com.esriau.dekho.view.original.CoordinatesView  - initilization
6:58:01:545 pm  [INFO] au.com.esriau.dekho.business.AbstractDelegate  - calling ConfigurationService.getCoordinateSystems
6:58:01:545 pm  [DEBUG] au.com.esriau.dekho.business.AbstractDelegate  - args: (Array)#0
  [0] "0A86A336:0137C62A4BBD:ADB6:1191EBC5"
6:58:01:546 pm  [INFO] au.com.esriau.dekho.view.original.ScaleView  - initilization
6:58:01:991 pm  [ERROR] au.com.esriau.dekho.utilities.AlertUser  - a fault has occurred
    - Fault Details:
    - Fault Code: Server.Processing.DuplicateSessionDetected
    - Fault String: Detected duplicate HTTP-based FlexSessions, generally due to the remote host disabling session cookies. Session cookies must be enabled to manage the client connection correctly.
```

I found some great links through SE-SO, that gave me [a good explanation](http://www.alexglosband.com/2010/03/avoiding-duplicate-session-detected-errors-in-lcds-and-blazeds/) of this error.

- Cookies are not disabled in my browser, so can rule that out.
- I have not implemented load balancing at all on AWS, its just one instance im hitting.
- From looking at Firebug and Client side logs, I cant see any trace of the Flex App making two requests.

Therefore I am unsure on why this issue is specifically happening on AWS, but does not happen in our lab or on any of our clients self-hosted machines, or an instance we have on [IBMs Iaas](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/au/solution/cloud_progression/longhaus.html) platform.

**Has anyone seen this happen before (specifically with with AWS in the mix) and seen a workaround?**

FYI: I am the tester and not the developer, but can get more info if required.  Please ask via comments.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have cross-domain in place? It might be the problem. Moreover it seems that while the first request is not over, a new request has been made which will lead to duplicate session problem.